# Troubles with a UIView into a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiimageview

I'm trying to load a `UIImageView` in a cell. 
My cell contains a `UIVIew` (gray color)

[image]

But when trying to load the `UIImageView` with same frame of `UIView`, my `UIImageView` has the frame of my cell and the description is behind

[image]

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 409
    self.tableView.sectionHeaderHeight = 257
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellPublicacion") as? PerfilTableViewCell
    //cell?.autoresizesSubviews = false

    let post = publicacionesArray[indexPath.row]


        cell?.avartarImage.image = avatar
        cell?.nombreLabel.text = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("NOMBRE") as? String
        cell?.fechaLabel.text = post.fecha
        cell?.comentariosLabel.text = "\(post.comentarios.count) comentarios"
        cell?.likesLabel.text = "\(post.likes.count) likes"
        cell?.tag = indexPath.row
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.frame = (cell?.generalView.frame)!
        cell?.generalView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.imageFromUrl(post.imageThum) 
return cell!
}
```

I need a `UIView` in my cell because I'm loading `UIControls` in another cell

[image]

What is wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using auto-layout in story board?? Can you show some more code?

Comment: Yes, I'm using autolayout

Comment: Is the description a separate item from the UIView/UIImageView?

Comment: What is the contentMode of the image view?

Comment: Mode: Scale to Fill

Comment: pls set clips to bounds to yes of cell?.generalView

Comment: @MikeAlter Already, but nothing is going on